# Symmetry of theory on static electric field background

Tags: quantum-field-theory, electric-fields, symmetry, field-theory

Let's consider complex scalar field in static homogeneous background electric field $E_z = E = const$, or in terms of vector potential $A_z = -Et$ or in another gauge $A_0 = -Ez$.

Without electric field theory have $Poincare_{3+1}$ symmetry.

In background field it is clear, this system have $Poincare_{2+1}$ (translations and Lorentz rotations in 2+1 space) and translations along $z$ symmetry group.

My instructor claimed that **this system have bigger symmetry group, and dimension of this group is equal to dimension of $Poincare_{3+1}$ group**.

Is this statement correct?

How this symmetry acts on coordinates? Or it is symmetry must acts only on complex scalar field?